# symfony2 rendering parial views in the controller and passing it as argument to the main render

Tags: symfony

I want to build a simple page in symfony2 with 2 tabs
think of the tabs as links that look like tabs.
when clicking on the link (tab) another page is loaded (full page load)
however I do not want to duplicate my main view so I want to render the contents of the tabs as partial views.

main.twig
.... my main view....
.... links styles as tabs....
tab contents
.... footer

tab1.twig (this is my partial for tab1)
.... some contents - need to have access to some variables also

tab2.twig (this is my partial for tab2)
.... some contents - need again to have access to some variables but not the same ones as tab1

in symfony1 (or any other framework) I'd just render tab1 or tab2 (depending on action) my tab contents and put it as argument in the main view 
this->render('main', array(
.....
'tabContents' => $this->renderPartial('tab2', array(...params...),
.....
);

question is, how do I do that in symfony2?
preferably not through twig render (would like to render my partial in a var within my controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function mainAction()
    {
        $tab1 = $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:tab1_template.html.twig'
            , array('arg1' => $arg1));
        // do sth
        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:main.html.twig', 
            array('tab1' => $tab1->getContent));
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to `->getContent()` on `$tab1`.

Comment: @ptheofan Was it working? Or you need another solution?